# How can I attach an image to an email from an URL using nodemailer and request modules in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm new to javascript and node.js and trying to learn it by doing something useful. So, I want to send an email with an image as attachment. The image will be retrieved from a remote server by issuing HTTP GET request and send to an email address using Gmail via nodemailer (SMTP)

[By reading the docs and looking through examples](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#attachments), I managed to send an email without attachment, but I can't figure out how to send it by using Streams. I used the following code, but it returns en error which I can't fix myself and need help:

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var request = require('request');
var config = require('../config');
var mailer;

mailer = function (opts) {
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
            user: config.GmailAuth.email,
            pass: config.GmailAuth.password
        }
    });

    var mailOptions = {
        from: opts.from, // sender address
        to: opts.to, // list of receivers
        subject: opts.subject, // Subject line
        html: opts.body,  // html body
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: 'screenshot.png',
                content: request(opts.imageUrl)  // <-- Error here 
            }
        ]
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
}

mailer({
        from: config.GmailAuth.email,
        to: config.sendToAddress, 
        subject: 'TEST SUBJECT',
        body: 'TEST MESSAGE BODY',
        imageUrl: 'URL_to_an_image_for_HTTP_GET_request'
       });
```

The following error occurs:

```
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: write after end
    at writeAfterEnd (_stream_writable.js:159:12)
    at Encoder.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:204:5)
    at Encoder.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:433:10)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\graphite_monitor\node_modules\
buildmail\src\buildmail.js:573:35)
    at Request.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\graphite_monitor\node_modul
es\request\request.js:820:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Try changing this:

```
attachments: [
  {
    filename: 'screenshot.png',
    content: request(opts.imageUrl)  // <-- Error here 
  }
]
```

to:

```
attachments: [
  {
    filename: "pin-marker.png",
    path: "http://img.mapeando.net/map/pin-marker.png", // <-- should be path instead of content
    cid: "pin-marker.png"
  }
]
```

Comment: I've tried that code, it added an attacment but it didn't download the image, it just attached a .txt file called 'screenshot.png' with the link inside the document

Comment: No, this isn't working either. [By looking through the docs more carefully](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#attachments), I found that passing any String as a content just adds a text file as an attachment with that String in the body (which makes sense), quote:

_content - String, Buffer or a Stream contents for the attachment_

Comment: @m-a-ge I've tested myself, I've received an email with an image.

Comment: hm, the computer on wich the code is running is under proxy server and I send HTTP GET requests using **https** protocol.
I guess my configuration is the issue here. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to make it work using PassThrough Streams ([here is somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808871/node-using-a-passthrough-stream-to-nodemailer)), here is working code (add changes where needed in my initial code):

```
var PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;

var nameOfAttachment = 'screenshot.png';
var imageUrlStream = new PassThrough();
request
     .get({
             proxy: 'http://YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME:3129', // if needed
             url: opts.imageUrl
         })
     .on('error', function(err) {
             // I should consider adding additional logic for handling errors here
             console.log(err);
    })
     .pipe(imageUrlStream);

var mailOptions = {
    from: opts.from, // sender address
    to: opts.to, // list of receivers
    subject: opts.subject, // Subject line
    html: opts.body, // html body
    attachments: [
        {
            filename: nameOfAttachment,
            content: imageUrlStream
        }
    ]
};
```

I hope it'll help other beginners